# xml schema for validating multiple xml files

Tags: xsd

Currently we have a set of related xml files(4 files) to represent a single entity.
One xml file may refer to an element in another xml file. How can we write the XSD for validating this scenario?

```
EG:
XMLFile1:

<Actors>
  <Actor id="A1">
    <Name>Name1</Name>
    <Movies>
      <Movie Id="M1" />
      <Movie Id="M2" />
    </Movies>
  </Actor>
  <Actor id="A2">
    <Name>Name2</Name>
    <Movies>
      <Movie Id="M2" />
      <Movie Id="M3" />
    </Movies>
  </Actor>
</Actors>

XMLFile2:
<Movies>
  <Movie Id="M1">
    <Name>Name1</Name>
  </Movie>
  <Movie Id="M2">
    <Name>Movie2</Name>
  </Movie>
</Movies>
```

Now in the two examples, Actor id="A2" refers to movie Movie id="M3" which doesn't exist.
how do we validate the cross references between the two files?

Answer (score 0):

You need, with some external process (xpath, xslt...) collect the movies ids from xmlfile1, and generate an xml schema with an enum type (for instance) wich test ids in xmlfile2.